# How can I put unescaped XML into the XmlText field for a class?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a class where I want to put XML (HTML, actually) that is unescaped.  It does not conform to a specification since it can be arbitrary html.  How can I achieve that declaratively?

Ex:

```
public class Material
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "mattext")]
    public string MaterialText { get; set; }


    public bool ShouldSerializeMaterialText()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MaterialText);
    }
}
```

If you put: `<p>test</p>` into `MaterialText`, it produces `&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;` in it's serialized output.  How can I modify this to produce the string literal AS XML instead of an escaped sequence?

To be clear, the output I'm looking for is: `<mattext><p>test</p></mattext>`

Btw - This isn't my first choice, but it is someone else's schema that must, unfortunately, be adhered to.

Thanks!

Comment: You do not want to put the "inner XML" inside a CDATA node?

Comment: You can either put it within CDATA or put XmlIgnore in MaterialText and add another property which returns XmlElement based upon the XML inside of MaterialText.

Comment: @D.R. - I would LOVE to put it in CDATA, but unfortunately the specification I'm relegated to adhering to will only pass validation if it's built the way I described.

Comment: Then you should go for the second property returning an XmlElement based on the MaterialText element. Do you know how or should I show an example?

Comment: @D.R. A brief example would be wonderful if you don't mind!  I don't spend much time working with XML.

Comment: Formulated my non-CDATA-approach as answer, hope it is what you've been looking for :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use a CDATA section, you have to use the following workaround:

```
public class Material
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string MaterialText { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "mattext")]
    public XmlElement MatText
    {
        get {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(MaterialText);
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }
        set { /* implement in a similar way */ }
   }
```

(you could of course add some kind of caching for the getter)